# Use many tables with few columns or few tables with many columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm just wondering what is usually the best way to set up databases and tables in MySQL when working with products.
I have already set up a table with a lot (50-60) of columns for our products. We are using that and it works, but I've run into some problems. Nothing serious, always been able to work around them for the most part, although sometimes I wonder if I could have made queries faster with a different setup.

The current table contains columns like: product_id, variant_id, ecommerce_product_id, ecommerce_variant_id, name, dsecription, translation_of_name, translation_of_description. variant_price, variant_color, variant_size, last_updated, last_received, inventory_1, inventory_2, inventory_4, etc.

The variant_id is a primary/unique key, as each product_id has many variants.

I've had to add many of the columns along the way, as we start doing something new. To begin with, the table had probably just around half of the columns it has now.

I'm wondering if I should have, to begin with, had many tables with fever columns (2-5 columns in each):
Such as: product_id_to_variant_id, prices, product_id_to_ecommerce_id, translations_from_lang_1_to_lang_2, variant_colors, variant_sizes, inventory_levels, etc.

Do you know how this is usually done and why it is better than my current setup?
I'm really not sure if this would speed up my queries or even slow them down, as I would have to have a lot of JOINs in my SELECT queries and a lot more INSERTs when I store the data.

Comment: More tables, fewer columns in each: generally better. Read about entity-relationship modeling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model and database normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization  And, don't worry. Many real-world databases have similar problems to yours. Advising you how to fix yours is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks! I searched for info on normalization and that helped a lot.

Comment: Do _not_ splay an array across columns (eg, inventory_4).  Make another table.  Ditto for multiple translations.